# Rails Validation - Remove or Modify Nested Model Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, rails-i18n

I have a few name-spaced Models, with relationships to each other as such:

`my_ns/main.rb`

```rb
module MyNs
  class Main < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :secondary

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :secondary, allow_destroy: true
  end
end
```

`my_ns/secondary.rb`

```rb
module MyNs
  class Secondary < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :main
    has_many :tertiary

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tertiary, allow_destroy: true
  end
end
```

`namespace/tertiary.rb`

```rb
module MyNs
  class Tertiary < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :secondary

    validate :custom_method

    private

    def custom_method
      errors.add(:thing, :custom_method_translation) if # condition
    end
  end
end
```

I then have a form that lets me add a `main`, multiple `secondary` and `tertiary` instances. This all works great, until I try to validate that `custom_method`. When the validation fails, and `errors.add(:thing, ...)` is triggered, the validation message appears as such:

> Secondary tertiary thing is not valid.

Basically, I want this to say "Tertiary's thing is not valid." I've seen [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486570/rails-omit-model-name-from-nested-validation-error-messages) which alludes to using [ActiveRecord's `i18n`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

`config/locales/en.yml`:

```yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      main_model/nested_model:
        key: 'Key'
```

The thing is, my models are nested more than 1 level, and have namespaces. I've tried things like:

```yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_ns/main/secondary/tertiary:
        thing: 'Thing'

# OR

en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_ns/main/my_ns/secondary/my_ns/tertiary:
        thing: 'Thing'

# OR

en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_ns/main:
        my_ns/secondary:
          my_ns/tertiary:
            thing: 'Thing'
```

And nothing has worked... The error message still appears as "Secondary tertiary thing is not valid".

Does anyone know how to handle this with nested, namespaced Models? Is this something that *can* be handled? Alternatively, if there's a way to stop Rails from attempting to prepend the Model chain, that would work too. I just need the error to say "Thing is invalid", or "Tertiary's thing is invalid", etc. I don't want to see "Secondary tertiary ..."

Comment: Not a proper solution, but you can add the error to the :base instead of :thing. This way only the error message will be shown directly

Comment: I tried that too actually, but when I did `errors.add(:base, : custom_method_translation) if # ...` the error changes to `Secondary tertiary base is not valid` instead of `Secondary tertiary thing is not valid`  (well, it actually said "translation missing ..."; had to add `:base` to `en.yml` too, which seems... odd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19863 it looks similar to yours.

Instead of adding complete chain from top model, try directly adding from the `secondary` model

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      secondary/tertiary:
        thing: 'Thing'
```

Comment: Same issue; it doesn't seem to like the namespace, which the linked GitHub Issue doesn't have. I'm almost positive this would work with `main`, `secondary` and `tertiary` if they didn't have namespaces, like `secondary/tertiary: thing: 'Thing'`, but `my_ns/secondary/tertiary` (or any other permutation) doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: Yeah right, after adding the error can you try to check the `.errors.keys` on the main model

Comment: `errors.add(:thing, :custom_method_translation)` followed by `abort errors.keys.inspect` shows `[:thing]`. On the main model, i.e. `@main.save`, followed by `abort @main.errors.keys.inspect`, then I see `[:'secondary.tertiary.thing']`

Comment: So this _does_ actually work, but the correct key was `secondary/tertiary: thing: 'Thing'`; apparently you don't use namespace at all.

Comment: Ohh great to hear that. I will update the answer please approve it.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for the tip on checking the `@main.errors.keys`; that was the hint I needed to apply the translation from the chain  For the longest time, I had been checking `errors.keys` (or similar) on `tertiary`, since that was the model triggering the error, but wasn't the model being directly validated.